# Modify list of figures in .sty file

Tags: floats

My .sty file has the following code for `\listoffigure`:

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{comment}
\RequirePackage{epsfig}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\renewcommand*\l@figure[2]{%
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{27\p@}%
    \begingroup
        \begin{singlespace}
            \hyphenpenalty 10000
            \exhyphenpenalty 10000
            \parindent \z@
            \rightskip \@pnumwidth
            \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
            \leavevmode
            \advance\leftskip75\p@
            \hskip -\leftskip
            \MakeUppercase{FIGURE}
            \hskip 0.05in\mbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{5.0in}{#1}\end{minipage}}
            \nobreak\hfil
            \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
            \vskip 7\p@ 
        \end{singlespace}
        \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
\fi
}
```

And it generates this:

> FIGURE 1.1 Some figure.

But I would like to change it to

> FIGURE 1.1 : Some figure.

Comment: It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify matters and use [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) if you're not already using [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) or another heavyweight class:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{0.7in}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{One}
\begin{figure}
\caption{\label{fig:one} Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]